# is this a function or an object being returned?

Tags: javascript

```
const {sum, subtract} = require('./math')



let result, expected
result = sum(3, 7)
expected = 10
expect(result).toBe(expected)


function expect(actual) {
  return {
    toBe(expected) {
      if (actual !== expected) {
        throw new Error(`${actual} is not equal to ${expected}`)
      }
    },
  }
}
```

is toBe{...} and object or a function?

It is used as a function when you call expect(result).toBe(expected).However, in the expect function definition it looks like an object because it doesn't have a function keyword. However objects do not accept parameters. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `toBe` is a function.

Comment: Well technically, functions *are* objects...

Comment: https://dev.to/sarah_chima/enhanced-object-literals-in-es6-a9d

Comment: @Li357 why can you create a function without declaring the keyword function?

Comment: @AndrewRivera methods and arrow functions don't use the keyword.

Comment: Your function is returning an object that has a property `toBe` which is a function. It's using a method shorthand to define the function. It's basically the same as `{ toBe: function(expected) {/*..etc */} }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to ES6 syntax, Search and read some article online.

Function expect is returning an object (return {});
That Object has a function called toBe(Its ES6 way of writing function inside object that you can omit keyword function).

Similarly inside ES6 classes there is no need to use the keyword function